# How to only get variable every few seconds and update it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form where maintenance employees at my company fill out at the end of the day to describe what they did that day. Some fill it out on their phones sometimes. They complained that if they got a call or text they would loose their log they had typed up.

So what I did is store the form values into PHP SESSION variables via AJAX and echo out the variable if the form is reloaded as long as they're signed in.

This is one of input fields:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="8to10" id="d8to10" placeholder="8 to 10 am" rows="8">
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['d8to10'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['d8to10'], ENT_QUOTES);} ?>
</textarea>
<span id="saved1"><span>
```

This is the corresponding Javascript that grabs the field's value and sends it through AJAX to get store into the SESSION variable.

```
$('#d8to10').on("keyup", function(){

    var d8to10 = $(this).val();
    $('#saved1').css('display', 'none');

    d8to10 = encodeURIComponent(d8to10);
    //console.log(d8to10);

    var ajaxRequest;
    clearTimeout(ajaxRequest);
        ajaxRequest = setTimeout(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'Includes/dailyLogCacheLog.php',
                data: 'd8to10=' + d8to10,
                success: function(r) {
                    $('#saved1').css('display', 'inline');
                    $('#saved1').html('<p>Saved</p>');
                }
            });
        }, 3000, d8to10);

});
```

So what I want to do now and can't figure out how to do right is to only grab the variable every 5 or 10 seconds as they type and save it in that time frame. This is because now the AJAX is being called after every letter typed up and they're complaining that the saved message is blinking too much.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just update when user click a button/submit a form???

Comment: Put the `keyup` callback inside a `setTimeout` with a 5-second delay.

Comment: That would require the user to click the button, which the problem is they're getting random calls or texts at times when they're filling out the form and won't be able to click the button when this happens.

Comment: Wrap your function in another `setTimeout(<func>,<msec>);` to create a timer event versus an event on every keyup. The event on keyup isn't necessary.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer, I tried something like that but that just delays the keyup event five seconds and THEN does the AJAX letter by letter after that.

Comment: We had similar system in my prev job, and the best solution was to update data on submit, as @A.Wolff suggest. But daily meeting is the best solution I think.

Comment: For auto save use localStorage ... will not require extra server load making all these requests. Clear storage on submit success

Comment: @Petroff on submit I am unsetting the SESSION variables storing the log because once submitted it gets emailed and there's no worry about losing their log anymore.

Comment: @charlietfl, ok. I'll look into that.

Comment: @AbrahamA. So you should rethink all your application logic/design. Now if you want true full-duplex appli, use websockets

Comment: @AbrahamA. Save the date in the datebase and add cronjob to send the email at the end of the day...

Comment: @Petroff this doesn't get store in a database. It solely gets emailed on submit.

Comment: @A.Wolff I've never heard of websockets. I'll look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick, this basically only executes the ajax about three seconds after the user stops typing. If you want to have multiple calls while the user types, you can remove the clearTimeout and abort calls.

```
var timeout_d8to10;
var xhr_d8to10;
$('#d8to10').on("keyup", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (timeout_d8to10) {
        clearTimeout(timeout_d8to10);
    }
    if ( xhr_d8to10) {
        xhr_d8to10.abort();
    }
    timeout_d8to10 = setTimeout( function () {
        var d8to10 = $this.val();
        d8to10 = encodeURIComponent(d8to10);

        $('#saved1').css('display', 'none');
        xhr_d8to10 = $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Includes/dailyLogCacheLog.php',
            data: 'd8to10=' + d8to10,
            success: function(r) {
                $('#saved1').css('display', 'inline');
                $('#saved1').html('<p>Saved</p>');
            }
          });

    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was working on something else. But yeah, I tried your code and it works so good! I marked your code as the answer because I think saving after the typing is done is better rather than while the typing is going.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of firing your ajax on every `keyup` event when the document loads put your ajax call in a `setInterval` function that saves the contents of the `textarea` at the desired interval:

```
var saveInterval; // to store ID in case you want to stop this later

$(document).ready(function() {
    // call saveContent every 3 seconds
    saveInterval = window.setInterval(saveContent, 3000);
});

function saveContent() {
    var d8to10 = $(this).val();
    $('#saved1').css('display', 'none');

    d8to10 = encodeURIComponent(d8to10);
    //console.log(d8to10);

    var ajaxRequest;

    ajaxRequest = function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Includes/dailyLogCacheLog.php',
            data: 'd8to10=' + d8to10,
            success: function(r) {
                $('#saved1').css('display', 'inline');
                $('#saved1').html('<p>Saved</p>');
            }
        });
    }, d8to10);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the comments section? If you are giving an answer to this sort of question, one expects to see some code demonstrating what you are trying to explain.

Comment: So in your example, where would I place the code to get the variable and store?

Comment: @AbrahamA. see the `saveContent()` function I added - I ported over most of the code you used in your example but removed the `setTimeout` call because it is no longer necessary.

Comment: @bwegs, ok let me try it out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If your intent was to have the Auto-Save feature of the field, similar to how gmail would save drafts, then I believe you are going to need a separate ajax call. As bwegs suggested, use a setInterval. If you absolutely must keep the keyup call, then just add something like this below it

```
function getFreshValue() {
  var newVal;

  $.get('someUrl')
    .then(function(data) {
      // Logic that handles inserting the new value
      // and / or making sure there is a valid value first
    });
}

setInterval(getFreshValue, 7500) // 7.5 second interval
```

EDIT: I really don't think there is a way to get around this without multiple calls. Unless you do it on an interval of keystrokes (every 10-15 keypresses for example).

Hoping someone else can do better?

Comment: I don't have to absolutlely use keyup. I used because that worked thus far. But any other way as long as it works can be used.